# Liferay and export LDAP account

Tags: ldap, openldap, liferay

I have this problem:

I have enabled Liferay to import and export users from/to OpenLDAP server.

When I create a user in Liferay I obtain this page:

[image]

So, I have create a new user and Liferay has assigned to it a password (3zbPk6KA).

But.. if I try to login with new user (and generated password) I obtain  the error message of incorrect credentials.
In LDAP server I can see the new account but, the corresponding password seems to be different from that generated by Liferay..

In Java console i read this waring:
14:20:15,882 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-6][LDAPAuth:208] Passwords do not match for userDN cn=myUser,ou=users,dc=myProject,dc=com

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug of Liferay:

- See following issue: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-43045

Answer (score 0):

The Encryption must match between Liferay and your LDAP server.

You need to set **ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm** in portal-ext.properties

Comment: ok, I have set the ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm in my portal-ext.properties file (for example SHA) and... How can I know the corresponding encryption algorithm in OpenLDAP?